# Network impersonation fails while trying to copy a file to different machine

Tags: c#, .net, iis, windows-services

Earlier, We were using a website in IIS to move a file to a different machine. Now we wanted to free this task from the UI thread, so we moved the movement logic to a background windows service. But now the network impersonation is failing with below error:

> Multiple connections to a server or shared resource by the same user,
> using more than one user name, are not allowed. Disconnect all
> previous connections to the server or shared resource and try again

The credentials are stored at a central location, so they are the same for both the IIS process and the background service. The movement is working fine for internal environments. But when it is deployed to some external environments, it fails.

What can be done here?

Comment: Involve your domain administrators to review the related configuration. Depending on how you store the credentials (but you didn't describe clearly), they might not be used to pass to another machine.

Comment: But the credentials are working fine from the IIS process, but they are not working from the background service hosted on the same machine.

Comment: Have you tried to create a different Domain Name System (DNS) alias for the remote server, and then use this alias to connect to the network share? Please refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/cannot-connect-to-network-share#symptoms).